# Android and Eclipse dev environment

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I've found a lot of posts on the issue but still can't seem to figure it out... and I'm getting really frustrated. I've already set up the dev environment but for some reason it stopped working today. Here goes:

When I try to create a new Android emulator I get an error. Google revealed that the reason for this error was that I had a non-english character in my C:/Users/*Non-english character*/.androiddirectory. So, I changed this using a user variable (ANDROID_SDK_HOME) and set it to a new location.
The thing is, now I get another error instead when I try to create a new AVD.
In Eclipse it says: "SDK Manager] Error: null". If I try and create a new AVD by using just the SDK Manager it says: "invalid command-line parameter: Files.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'."
I've understood that this has to do with my Android install location, however I've already changed this to: C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\ in order to get rid of the space.

I'm getting very confused and frustrated... =/ Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Alright - some success after a fair amount of trial and error.
What I have to do is basically to create my AVD by starting the SDK Manager. I can't start the AVD from here though. I can't start them in Eclipse by using the SDK Manager from there - instead I have to run my projects as Android Applications and then the AVD will fire up. In order to change between different AVDs I basically have to change which one in Run Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your SDK to C:\android-sdk. That way, there are no non-standard characters in the path. It fixed the issue for me.